# How to convert string list into float list

Tags: python, string, list

I am currently trying to make a program that converts the elements in a string list into a float list. Though a few adjustments have to be made.

1. The user enters a "colon" between each typed number,  which will then divide the elements in the list. (This works atm)
2. Every value has to be outputted in 1 decimal, which I have been trying to do with:

   ```
   print(f'{word:.1f}')
   ```

   But haven't been able to do it correctly.

Input: `5:2:4`

Output: `[5.0, 2.0, 4.0]`

Would appreciate some recommendations.

```py
user_list = input("Enter values:")
word = user_list.split(":")
print(word)
```

Comment: You've got the basic idea down, now you can do a `float()` conversion, perhaps even list comprehension with it to write tighter code, and you'd have your list. Where exactly are you having your issues?

Comment: @Frontear I struggle with converting the list to float, specifically because of the ":" is a string and can't be converted into a float in this case. Kinda stuck in that way, hopefully, I could share my issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In the future, please start with your own research. I found that question just by googling "python" plus your question title. As well, please provide a [mre], meaning remove anything that's not relevant to the problem like the `input()` and `.split()` that are working correctly already. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: @Ertu `word` doesn't contain any colons, so what do you mean exactly? (sorry, I should have asked this first, but I didn't read the comments until now)

Comment: @wjandrea Hello, I had checked that question before, but didn't find it helpful in my case. I also did the research regarding this, but failed in coding the program correctly. That is why I asked here on Stackoverflow. The program itself has to contain input(), that's why I included it. Split() was also added to show others the method I used in this case. If this was not relevant, then I apologize on my part.

Comment: @ertu How didn't you find it helpful? To me, it addresses your problem directly: `[float(i) for i in word]` from the [top answer](/a/1614247/4518341)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list(map(float, word.split(':')))
```

This will convert each of the number to float

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through each item in array `word`, convert to `float`, then round to one decimal using `round()` and append it to a new array:

```
user_list = input("Enter values:")
word = user_list.split(":")
newlist = []
for num in word:
    newlist.append(round(float(num), 1))
print(newlist)
```

Note that this is what you want if you are expecting the user to include longer decimal floats such as `3.432` in their input, and wish them to be outputted as `3.4`. If you are assuming the user will only include ints in the input, Sakshi's answer is likely the most compressed solution to do it

Comment: Appreciate the information!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have validated the inputs, a nice way to do this is through a list comprehension

```
input = "5:2:4"
user_list = input.split(":")

float_list = [float(x) for x in user_list]
print(float_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a map function into a list function. Your word variable is already being split by ':'. Try:

```
list(map(float, word))
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
word = user_list.split(":")
```

Takes a string (`user_list`) and splits it into parts over occurrences of `:`. The result is a *list* of strings. For example, `'alice:bob'.split(":")` would become `['alice', 'bob']`.

You print all of `word`, so you're printing a list and that's why you should be  seeing `['5', '2', '4']`, since that's the representation in text of the list, still in strings.

If you want to print the numbers separated by commas and spaces (for example), with a single digit of precision, you could do:

```
print(', '.join(f'{float(w):.1f}' for w in word))
```

This loops over the strings in `word`, turns them into floating point numbers, then formats them, collects all of them and then `.join()` puts them all together with `', '` in between.

Comment: Appreciate the help and information, would it be possible if you could further explain on why you used ', ' ?

Comment: Just as a suggestion, your question didn't make it explicit how you expect the numbers to be separated when you print them, so I decided to separate them with `', '`, so that the result looks like "5.0, 2.0, 4.0" - if you need each number on a new line, you'd separate then with `'\n'`, and you can pick anything else of course.