# Evaluating a string as a numpy array

Tags: python, list-comprehension, eval

My team is migrating from **Clickhouse** to **Azure Data Explorer** (ADX). We are currently experiencing difficulties to query our data from ADX: the queried values are correct, but the data are read as a **string** rather than as an array of **floats**.

Here is an example string:

`mydummystring='[1.0,2.0,3.0][4.0,5.0,6.0][6.0,7.0,8.0]'`

In order to convert this string to a numpy array, I found this workaround based on list comprehension (inspired by [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70117942/6440589)):

```
import numpy as np
mynumpyarray = np.array([np.array(x) for x in eval('['+mydummystring.replace('][', '],[')+']')])
```

Is there a better (safer?) way to achieve this conversion? I know that it would be better to read the data correctly in the first place, but for now I am looking for a robust way to convert the output string to actual numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), which only parses Python literal structures and does not run arbitrary code.

```py
from ast import literal_eval
s = '[1.0,2.0,3.0][4.0,5.0,6.0][6.0,7.0,8.0]'
np_arr = np.array([np.array(x) for x in literal_eval('['+s.replace('][', '],[')+']')])
```

Note that a list comprehension is not necessary to create the NumPy array.

```py
np.array(literal_eval('['+s.replace('][', '],[')+']'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Unmitigated. I will review the difference between `eval` and ast's `literal_eval`. Anyways, I imagine that skipping the list comprehension will make the conversion more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `'[1.0,2.0,3.0][4.0,5.0,6.0][6.0,7.0,8.0]'` to `'[[1.0,2.0,3.0],[4.0,5.0,6.0],[6.0,7.0,8.0]]'` with `str.replace` the use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

```
import ast
mydummystring = '[1.0,2.0,3.0][4.0,5.0,6.0][6.0,7.0,8.0]'
mydummystring = '[' + mydummystring.replace('][', '],[') + ']'
mydummystring = ast.literal_eval(mydummystring)
arr = np.array(mydummystring)
print(arr)
```

Or use [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html):

```
import json
mydummystring = '[1.0,2.0,3.0][4.0,5.0,6.0][6.0,7.0,8.0]'
mydummystring = '[' + mydummystring.replace('][', '],[') + ']'
mydummystring = json.loads(mydummystring)
arr = np.array(mydummystring)
print(arr)
```

---

```
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [4., 5., 6.],
       [6., 7., 8.]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I would have never thought of using json's `loads` method to evaluate the input string.

Answer (score 1):

Without any extra library but with string prepeocessing.
[np.fromstring](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) returns a *1 dimensional* array, so find the shape, format it and then reshape.

```
s = '[1.0,2.0,3.0][4.0,5.0,6.0][6.0,7.0,8.0]'
shape = s.count('['), s.count('][')+1
# flat array format
s = s.strip('][').replace('][', ',')
a = np.fromstring(s, sep=',', dtype=float).reshape(shape)
```

Comment: Nice tip, @cards. I may end up counting the number of `']['` to ensure that I am not missing any data.